# LESSCSS escaping filter

Tags: css, less

I need my LESS file to compile the following filter:

```
filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'grayscale\'><feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0\'/></filter></svg>#grayscale");
```

I can't seem to figure out the correct syntax to escape it, as LESS is stripping the + sign and the spaces. I managed to keep the + sign by adding a backslash. But this did not work for the spaces. I'm sure it's super easy but I can't figure it out ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
filter: ~"url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'grayscale\'><feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0\'/></filter></svg>#grayscale')";
```

Comment: I tried this earlier and it didn't work. However, looking more closely I suspect my CSS minifier is being a d*ck. I'll look into it and if that's the case I will approve your answer. Tnx!

Comment: Yup, it's definitely my CSS compressor (recess --compress) which is acting up. Thanks for your answer. Hopefully I can get the compressor issues sorted tomorrow.

Comment: @DivZero what did you do to fix your compressor? I think I am having the same issue.

Comment: @LarkDavis I can hardly remember the issue but looked it up for you. It seems I was unable to get the "inline" filter to work so I had to "include it". This is my code:
  filter: url(http://www.domain.tld/css/filters.svg#grayscale); /* Firefox 3.5+, needs the file served from same domain because of security policies from FF. Filter inlining gives issues with the RECESS css compressor */